# Extracting GZipped data from the DATA frame in HTTP/2

Tags: gzip, http2

I've received the following DATA frame from https://example.com (is contains the HTML file).

```
Stream: DATA, Stream ID: 1, Length 606
    Length: 606
    Type: DATA (0)
    Flags: 0x01
        .... ...1 = End Stream: True
        .... 0... = Padded: False
        0000 .00. = Unused: 0x00
    0... .... .... .... .... .... .... .... = Reserved: 0x0
    .000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 = Stream Identifier: 1
    [Pad Length: 0]
    Reassembled body in frame: 37
    Data: 1f8b08003b81055200038d5441afd3300cbeef5798720169…
```

My understanding is that this data is gzipped.  When I save the decrypted data to a file and give it a `.gz` extension and attempt to extract it with 7-Zip I get an error though.  It can open the archive, see that there is a single file in there, but when I try to read it or extract it I just get an error.

[image: 7-Zip opened archive]
[image: Error when viewing]

This is a hex dump of the decrypted data.

```
0000   1f 8b 08 00 3b 81 05 52 00 03 8d 54 41 af d3 30
0010   0c be ef 57 98 72 01 69 5d f7 80 07 53 d7 56 20
0020   40 e2 02 1c e0 c2 31 6b dc d5 5a 93 94 24 ed 36
0030   a1 f7 df 71 db bd ae e5 ed 40 2b b5 8e 1d 7f fe
0040   6c c7 49 9e 49 93 fb 73 8d 50 7a 55 65 8b e4 f1
0050   87 42 66 0b e0 27 f1 e4 2b cc 3e 9f 84 aa 2b 84
0060   4f 46 09 d2 49 34 68 17 c3 16 85 5e 40 5e 0a eb
0070   d0 a7 41 e3 8b 70 13 40 94 4d 8c a5 f7 75 88 bf
0080   1b 6a d3 e0 a3 d1 1e b5 0f bb b0 01 e4 c3 2a 0d
0090   3c 9e 7c d4 85 df 8e 50 b7 90 b4 50 98 06 2d e1
00a0   b1 36 d6 4f fc 8f 24 7d 99 4a 6c 29 c7 b0 5f 2c
00b0   81 34 79 12 55 e8 72 51 61 7a 77 85 72 fe cc c9
00c0   74 0c 2e 81 73 e7 82 c1 b6 33 f2 0c 7f 7a b1 5f
00d0   8a fc b0 b7 a6 d1 32 cc 4d 65 6c 0c cf 8b 35 bf
00e0   af b6 e3 16 25 ec 9e 74 0c eb ab aa 16 52 92 de
00f0   cf 74 05 33 0d 0b a1 a8 3a c7 10 7c af 51 c3 0f
0100   a1 5d b0 84 e0 0b 56 2d 7a ca 05 7c c3 06 59 33
0110   2a 96 f0 c1 72 06 4b 70 bc 35 74 68 a9 b8 22 f6
0120   c2 43 ff 95 d4 4e 48 f7 e9 c7 f0 76 bd ae 4f 4f
0130   79 de a3 02 d1 78 73 83 ee fd cc e1 56 ee c5 24
0140   fe ce 58 89 36 b4 42 52 e3 62 b8 43 b5 9d 50 12
0150   71 45 fa b0 e4 7f 4b 8e 3c ca 09 c1 47 b8 d7 9b
0160   37 9b cd 04 b1 eb 45 28 31 37 56 78 32 cc 55 1b
0170   8d 53 d0 f7 0a 25 09 78 a1 c4 29 bc 64 f9 ae cb
0180   f2 e5 b4 65 f3 0e fe 4f 26 0f a3 34 2f e4 a4 98
0190   f3 8a cd fa 7e c3 f6 4f 69 d6 73 eb 58 ef b1 64
01a0   57 12 c3 37 89 fa 23 9a 75 f2 22 89 86 79 5c 24
01b0   5d 6a 3c 9e 4c f2 72 90 cb bb 27 a3 c9 aa c1 56
01c0   67 3f 4b 72 20 7b 3d b0 84 ce 8b 5d 45 ae e4 5e
01d0   78 03 3b 84 c6 b1 58 18 0b 54 55 8d f3 5d d5 5b
01e0   04 1c 10 1d cf 0f 7b e7 8d e2 01 73 2b f8 65 1a
01f0   ce f9 dc 39 81 67 e4 e1 e0 5d d0 f5 d5 eb 48 be
0200   34 8d 87 da 12 23 e7 86 4b 41 ba ef 27 f0 5a b8
0210   03 a7 de 07 ad d1 2a 72 8e 0d ab 24 aa 47 d6 09
0220   df 17 16 8b 34 e8 6e 8d 38 8a 8e c7 e3 8a 84 16
0230   2b 63 f7 d1 10 cf 45 97 68 41 f6 d5 58 e4 f0 8c
0240   a7 fa 18 ab 15 83 89 ac 07 4c a2 be 52 49 74 a9
0250   5b 34 5c 6f 7f 01 08 95 aa 8b f6 04 00 00
```

How do I decompress this data?

Answer (score 2):

Looks right to me. I suspect this is a problem with however you have extracted the DATA Frame, or 7Zip (don't have that on my machine).

Running the following in GitBash in Windows downloads the gzipped file (which might be over HTTP/1.1 probably depending on the version of curl you have installed, but ignore that for now, because I don't think this is an HTTP/2 problem):

```
$ curl --raw --compress https://example.com > /tmp/index.html.gz
```

At this point you can look at the raw hex (using `xxd /tmp/index.html.gz` for example) and see it's the exact same as what you've posted:

```
00000000: 1f8b 0800 3b81 0552 0003 8d54 41af d330  ....;..R...TA..0
00000010: 0cbe ef57 9872 0169 5df7 8007 53d7 5620  ...W.r.i]...S.V
00000020: 40e2 021c e0c2 316b dcd5 5a93 9424 ed36  @.....1k..Z..$.6
00000030: a1f7 df71 dbbd aee5 ed40 2bb5 8e1d 7ffe  ...q.....@+.....
00000040: 6cc7 499e 4993 fb73 8d50 7a55 658b e4f1  l.I.I..s.PzUe...
00000050: 8742 660b e027 f1e4 2bcc 3e9f 84aa 2b84  .Bf..'..+.>...+.
00000060: 4f46 09d2 4934 6817 c316 855e 405e 0aeb  OF..I4h....^@^..
00000070: d0a7 41e3 8b70 1340 944d 8ca5 f775 88bf  ..A..p.@.M...u..
00000080: 1b6a d3e0 a3d1 1eb5 0fbb b001 e4c3 2a0d  .j............*.
00000090: 3c9e 7cd4 85df 8e50 b790 b450 9806 2de1  <.|....P...P..-.
000000a0: b136 d64f fc8f 247d 994a 6c29 c7b0 5f2c  .6.O..$}.Jl).._,
000000b0: 8134 7912 55e8 7251 617a 7785 72fe ccc9  .4y.U.rQazw.r...
000000c0: 740c 2e81 73e7 82c1 b633 f20c 7f7a b15f  t...s....3...z._
000000d0: 8afc b0b7 a6d1 32cc 4d65 6c0c cf8b 35bf  ......2.Mel...5.
000000e0: afb6 e316 25ec 9e74 0ceb abaa 1652 92de  ....%..t.....R..
000000f0: cf74 0533 0d0b a1a8 3ac7 107c af51 c30f  .t.3....:..|.Q..
00000100: a15d b084 e00b 562d 7aca 057c c306 5933  .]....V-z..|..Y3
00000110: 2a96 f0c1 7206 4b70 bc35 7468 a9b8 22f6  *...r.Kp.5th..".
00000120: c243 ff95 d44e 48f7 e9c7 f076 bdae 4f4f  .C...NH....v..OO
00000130: 79de a302 d178 7383 eefd cce1 56ee c524  y....xs.....V..$
00000140: fece 5889 36b4 4252 e362 b843 b59d 5012  ..X.6.BR.b.C..P.
00000150: 7145 fab0 e47f 4b8e 3cca 09c1 47b8 d79b  qE....K.<...G...
00000160: 379b cd04 b1eb 4528 3137 5678 32cc 551b  7.....E(17Vx2.U.
00000170: 8d53 d0f7 0a25 0978 a1c4 29bc 64f9 aecb  .S...%.x..).d...
00000180: f2e5 b465 f30e fe4f 260f a334 2fe4 a498  ...e...O&..4/...
00000190: f38a cdfa 7ec3 f64f 69d6 73eb 58ef b164  ....~..Oi.s.X..d
000001a0: 5712 c337 89fa 239a 75f2 2289 8679 5c24  W..7..#.u."..y\$
000001b0: 5d6a 3c9e 4cf2 7290 cbbb 27a3 c9aa c156  ]j<.L.r...'....V
000001c0: 673f 4b72 207b 3db0 84ce 8b5d 45ae e45e  g?Kr {=....]E..^
000001d0: 7803 3b84 c6b1 5818 0b54 558d f35d d55b  x.;...X..TU..].[
000001e0: 041c 101d cf0f 7be7 8de2 0173 2bf8 651a  ......{....s+.e.
000001f0: cef9 dc39 8167 e4e1 e05d d0f5 d5eb 48be  ...9.g...]....H.
00000200: 348d 87da 1223 e786 4b41 baef 27f0 5ab8  4....#..KA..'.Z.
00000210: 03a7 de07 add1 2a72 8e0d ab24 aa47 d609  ......*r...$.G..
00000220: df17 168b 34e8 6e8d 388a 8ec7 e38a 8416  ....4.n.8.......
00000230: 2b63 f7d1 10cf 4597 6841 f6d5 58e4 f08c  +c....E.hA..X...
00000240: a7fa 18ab 1583 89ac 074c a2be 5249 74a9  .........L..RIt.
00000250: 5b34 5c6f 7f01 0895 aa8b f604 0000       [4\o..........
```

Then can use gunzip to view the file in the command line:

```
$ gunzip -c index.html.gz
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Domain</title>
...etc.
```

Or decompress it:

```
$ gunzip index.html.gz
$ cat index.html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Domain</title>
...etc.
```

So I would guess either 7zip doesn't like reading this file (but it seems to from a quick search online) or you are corrupting the saving of the data somehow before opening it in 7zip.

Comment: I suspect it's the latter.  I'll have another go an double check everything.